# where to place test-jgroups-jdbc_ping.xml jgroup file in JGroups configuration

Tags: java, linux, activemq-artemis, jgroups

In Artemis ActiveMQ Cluster documentation, it is specified that

> jgroups-file attribute. This is the name of JGroups configuration
> file. It will be used to initialize JGroups channels. Make sure the
> file is in the java resource path so that Apache ActiveMQ Artemis can
> load it.

I have configured the test-jgroups-file_ping.xml JGroups configuration file, but I don't know where to place that file. What does java resource path reffers to. What is the java resource path location in Linux machine

Answer (score 1):

ActiveMQ Artemis adds at [boot](https://github.com/apache/activemq-artemis/blob/2.15.0/artemis-boot/src/main/java/org/apache/activemq/artemis/boot/Artemis.java#L82) the `$ARTEMIS_HOME/etc` and `$ARTEMIS_INSTANCE/etc` to be searched for classes and resources after first searching in the parent class loader.

You can move the file defined with the tag `jgroups-channel` to the `$ARTEMIS_INSTANCE/etc` path if you are using the ActiveMQ Artemis [boot](https://github.com/apache/activemq-artemis/blob/2.15.0/artemis-boot/src/main/java/org/apache/activemq/artemis/boot/Artemis.java), ie `$ARTEMIS_INSTANCE/bin/artemis run`.

You can take a look to the [ActiveMQ Artemis Clustering with JGroups Example](https://github.com/apache/activemq-artemis/tree/2.15.0/examples/features/clustered/clustered-jgroups) for further details.

Comment: Thanks @Domenico Francesco Bruscino, I tried placing file in $ARTEMIS_INSTANCE/etc folder in both live and back up server of Artemis ActiveMq and it worked for me. Thanks once again

Comment: But now my live artemis node is working fine. Same I replicated in slave node but in slave while running "./artemis run" command, I am getting error. INFO  [org.apache.activemq.hawtio.plugin.PluginContextListener] Initialized artemis-plugin plugin
AMQ224000: Failure in initialisation: java.lang.IllegalStateException: AMQ219004: Failed to initialise session factory

Comment: Maybe your slave node is using the same http port of the live node, if not I would create a new question sharing your broker.xml files because it should not be related to your first issue question.